# Convert First Letter of Each Word to Uppercase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, uppercase

I have the following string, I want to convert every First Letter to Capital. I tried the following

`<h5>Offers from @providerDetail.ProviderName.ToLower()</h5>`

But it Lowered every letter of the words. How can I achieve it in MVC?

Comment: Is it really a duplicate? Will the solutions work in MVC razor syntax?

Comment: It is not difficult to test.

Comment: You can run any c# code in a view with razor (it would be just awful practice to do so) - that code belongs in the controller, not the view.

Comment: Create class capitalize in css and use it ... like this : 


capitalize  {
    text-transform:capitalize;
}